# JavaScript regex with variable pattern using RegExp constructor

Tags: javascript, regex

Having the variable

```html
var str = "asdasd asd 123213 100 Feet";
```

I can easily extract the string '100 Feet' using

```
str.match(/(\d+) feet/gi);
```

producing:

```
100 Feet
```

But let's say I want to specify the keyword 'feet' in a variable and use that in my regex evaluation - and so I attempt to use the RegExp constructor like below:

```js
var keyWord = 'feet';
var pattern = '(\\d+) ' + keyWord;     
//pattern evaluates into '(\d+) feet', seemingly equivalent to the pattern shown above

var regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'g', 'i');
var result = str.match(regex);
```

However, this does not match the string for some reason. Would anyone be able to shed some light into this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because `ignore case` flag is not applied. Should be:

```
var regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'gi');
```

[`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor doesn't have third param and `flag` param should consist of combination of different flags as simple chars.

Comment: Aha! I thought the constructor allowed the flags to be entered like so: RegExp(pattern, flag1, flag2) -> RegExp(pattern, 'g', 'i')

But, as you pointed out, RegExp(pattern, 'gi') does the trick!